# How do I finish an app on Android?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

I have an Android app on Android. The way it starts is that it has a main menu, then you click start, and that is where the main function is. I was wondering, once I am in an activity that is not on the bottom of the stack, I want to allow the user to exit the program. Is there a way to finish the entire application, not just the current activity?

Comment: you can find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478200/android-yes-i-want-to-close-the-app-i-opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to Mark's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238).

There are also some useful `Intent` flags, in particular [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), which will `finish` activities until the intent target is reached. This is used often for apps that begin with a login screen and need to go back to it when the user logs out.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not generally considered acceptable, you would do it like this:

```
System.exit(0)
```

Like I said though, this is not how Android apps work usually.

Edit: I guess I should be more clear in saying that it isn't generally acceptable. Google doesn't want apps forcing a close, as it can have unforeseen consequences. The way you *should* close your app is by manually finishing every activity.

Comment: Google requests that this be reserved for test cases at the most and should not be used in production code.

Comment: @CommonsWare: That's exactly why I said that it's not generally considered acceptable behavior for an app.

Comment: You will note that I did not say you were wrong. However, IMHO, "not generally considered acceptable" is a bit weaker than "Google says don't do that", which is why I wanted to clarify the point.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `System.exit(0)` command can have unforeseen consequences in your application lifecycle according to [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/63de8a9cdffa46a3), and as mentioned in other answers and comments is recommended against by Google for production code.

The [suggestion on this site](http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_exit_an_Android_application.rhtml) seems reasonable:

> Call `finish()`
>   on your activities.
>   If you have multiple activities to close, use `startActivityForResult()` and pass back a "close now" flag so you know to call `finish()` on the parent activity as well.